# Export content of a CDC window to a EMF file

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi, cdc

I am new to C++ and OpenGL. There is this C++ application someone wrote before (based on Linux), and I have to tweak it.

Basically in this application, there is a window containing a plot. Now this window supports functions to export the plot to bitmap (tga, jpg and bmp). We want to add another function to save the content of the plot as an Enhanced Meta File.

I managed to get hold of the CDC device handler and use the HDC of it to create an empty EMF with the same width/height as the plot, however I have no clue of how to migrate the CONTENT of the plot onto the EMF file. Is there any code to do this?

The code I am using to create the empty EMF file is as followed. Do appreciate any kind of idea or help!

```
CDC* dc = pWnd->GetDC();
HDC hdcRef;
hdcRef = dc->GetSafeHdc();

CRect rect;
pWnd->GetClientRect(rect);

// Convert client coordinates to .01-mm units.
// Use iWidthMM, iWidthPels, iHeightMM, and
int iWidthMM = GetDeviceCaps (hdcRef, HORZSIZE);  
int iHeightMM = GetDeviceCaps (hdcRef, VERTSIZE);  
int iWidthPels = GetDeviceCaps (hdcRef, HORZRES);  
int iHeightPels = GetDeviceCaps (hdcRef, VERTRES);  
rect.left = (rect.left * iWidthMM * 100) / iWidthPels;  
rect.top = (rect.top * iHeightMM * 100) / iHeightPels;  
rect.right = (rect.right * iWidthMM * 100) / iWidthPels;  
rect.bottom = (rect.bottom * iHeightMM * 100) / iHeightPels;

//::SetMapMode(hdcRef, MM_HIMETRIC);
HDC hdcMeta = CreateEnhMetaFile(hdcRef, "C:\\temp\\testEMF.emf", &rect, "Example metafile\0");
if (!hdcMeta) 
    GenAppWarningMsg("CreateEnhMetaFile", "Error");

// Set the device context back to its original state.  
SetMapMode(hdcMeta, MM_ANISOTROPIC); 
::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcRef);

HENHMETAFILE meta = CloseEnhMetaFile (hdcMeta);
```

Comment: To generate an EMF, ideally you would not save a bitmap but the individual lines, points, etc., to generate the plot, so that the result can be rendered at high quality.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Basically, you want to create a DC for the meta file (as you've done), and then ask the original code to render the plot to that DC.

The original code may have such a function.  If not, you may be able to trick it into rendering on your DC by sending the Windows message [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This isn't guaranteed to work, as some Windows don't implement a handler for WM_PRINTCLIENT, which WM_PRINT relies on.

If you can't get that to work (because the original code doesn't have a way to render to an arbitrary DC and you cannot modify the code to add that funcationality), then the best you can do is to get the bitmap file and BitBlt that directly to your `hdcMeta`.  This approach won't look as good if you try to stretch/shrink the EMF.